# Grid on reconfiguring the columns with locked and flex configs wont work

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridview, extjs5, locked

When I tried to reconfigure my grid in afterender with one of the columns having locked:true and flex:1, the view did not render.

I am facing this issue where I am trying to create(reconfigure) my grid dynamically based on the store's metadata change. I am calling reconfigure method but the columns are not getting locked.

enableLocking: true in grid config along with the above column configs doesnt work as well. 
It throws the following error: 
Uncaught TypeError: lockedGrid.getView(...).getScrollable is not a function

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/r05

Any solutions or pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks and Regards, 
PD

Answer (score 0):

Locked columns does not support a flex width.

If you inspect the console, you will see the following error:

Ext.grid.locking.Lockable.getColumnWidth(): Locked columns in an unsized locked side do NOT support a flex width. You must set a width on the Namecolumn.

[image]set a width on the Namecolumn.

I wonder why you would want to use reconfigure in afterrender. Grid reconfigure generally have a bunch of issues.

You can always dynamically set your columns when you have your store data ready.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Dshun.  I am creating my columns dynamically based on the metadata that loads along when store loads for the first time. I am using reconfigure in before/after render to achieve this. Locking is not working when I do reconfigure.

Comment: it does not need reconfigure. you can set up your grid when your store loads, add a listener on store load. the grid locking is working, however you cannot set flex to a locked column.